# Compare two tables, if not exists update or insert

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a two same tables.Database mysql.
How can I compare two tables?
Table1,Table2 - the same.. differences only in rows
IF in one table id key exists,update row.If key is not exists insert new row.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use MySQL replication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be to use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html), which is like INSERT, except that existing rows 'in the way' are deleted before the insert.

There's also [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) which is somewhat similar - does what you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

**upsert** http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/17/3-ways-to-write-upsert-and-merge-queries-in-mysql/